# Given a smooth hyperplane section Y of a variety X there exists a Lefschetz pencil of hyperplane sections of X containing Y

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, hodge-theory, complex-manifolds

Let $X$ be a variety contained in $\mathbb{P}^N$ and let $Y$ be a smooth  hyperplane section of $X$. I have read in page 54 of Voisin's book  "Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry II" the following:

there exists a  Lefschetz pencil of hyperplane sections  of $X$ of which $Y$ is one member.

I would like to know  why  this  is true. Any reference  for it will be also very helpful. Thank you very much :)!

Answer (score 8):

A pencil of hyperplane sections of $X$ corresponds to a line in the dual projective space $\check{\mathbb{P}}^N$. It is a Lefschetz pencil if and only if the line is transverse to the projectively dual variety
$$
\check{X} \subset \check{\mathbb{P}}^N.
$$
So, a restatement of your claim is that for a point $y \in \check{\mathbb{P}}^N$ not on $\check{X}$ there is a line through $y$ transverse to $\check{X}$, which is obvious --- just consider the linear projection map
$$
\pi_y \colon \check{X} \to \check{\mathbb{P}}^{N-1}
$$
from $y$, choose a point in the target not on the critical locus of $\pi_y$, and take the corresponding line.

Comment: Dear Sasha thank you very much  for your answer!...   could  you tell me how $\pi_y$ is defined and what   you mean for the critical locus of $\pi_y$?

Comment: $\pi_y$ is the linear projection $\mathbb{P}^N \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{N-1}$ with center at $y$, restricted to $\check{X}$. The critical locus, or rather the set of critical values, is the image of the union of the singular locus of $\check{X}$ and the set of points of $\check{X}$ at which the differential of $\pi_y$ is not surjective.

Comment: Dear Sasha thank you  very much! for the linear projection  $\pi_y$ with center  in $y$, you mean a notion similar to the Stereographic projection? could you suggest a reference where  I can read what exactly you mean :)...

Comment: Choose coordinates such that $y = (1:0:\dots:0)$. Then $$\pi_y(x_0:x_1:\dots:x_n) = (x_1:\dots:x_n).$$

Comment: Dear Sasha thank you very much for the clarifications :)!... I have the following questions: 1).  Why I need to choose a point in the target not on the critical locus of $\pi_y$?

Comment: 2). I know that a pencil of hyperplane sections of $X$ corresponds to a line in the dual projective space $\mathbb{P}^N$ and that it is a Lefschetz pencil if and only if the line is transverse to  the discriminant locus $\Delta_X$ of $X$ in the open dense set $\Delta_X^0$ (see Voisin's book page 45), but  your definition uses the  projectively dual variety  $\check{X}$, so.. are you saying that it is always true that $\Delta_X=\check{X}$?

Comment: 1) To get the transversality. 2) Yes, by definition.